# CellEditingTemplate in XAML

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, xaml

I have created a datagrid in silverlight having all textboxes(using CellEditingTemplate)..[image]

On click of save button i want to insert data of textboxes present in rows datagrid into database.
How could I achieve this??

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645914/loop-through-rows-in-silverlight-datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
TextBox txt = this.dtgrd.Columns[0].GetCellContent(list[0]) as TextBox;
```

It fetched the textbox inserted in following code and hence fetched the value stored in textbox.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width="*">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="txt_ID" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now fetched value could be easily stored using List.

Comment: What's `lst_str` and `dtgrd` ?

Comment: Plz specify those things in your answer, Don't expect from peoples that they would know it by themselves.

Comment: don't get it in a rude way my dude, I just want you to learn from your mistakes and be a better SO user and contributor...PEACE... :)

Answer (score 0):

First of All you should create your View Model classes.

```
public class Person 
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Address {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

then you create Observable Collection of this class and bind grid item source to it. 
in your template bind each column to it's property in the Person.

when you press save button in code behind you should call commit edit of the grid and then all of your data will be reflected to your observableCollection ... you can then save your data to db.

Comment: Before that, I need to access textbox in datagrid to fetch the text..for that i used "findname()" but still not accessible,how can i do that for following:                                                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width="*">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="txt_ID"></TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
     </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

Comment: @maatu share that `xaml` code in your question plz, edit your question and show us what you have tried so far.